# Is this a cross-domain or cross-protocol request?

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, cors, same-origin-policy

I've got an error that's a bit over my head to debug.
It's happening from an http GET in Angular2 that looks like this:

```
constructor(private http: Http) {}

...

this.http.get('someApi.abc.com/stuff?params`)
```

Which fails with an error that looks like this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://someApi.abc.com/stuff?params' to
>   'http://elsewhere.abc.com/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://local.abc.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I think there are 2 issues: a redirect I don't understand (possibly need to contact the someApi owner?) and a CORS issue.

My understanding is that the domain is: `abc.com`
And the protocol is: `http`
So there should be no CORS nonsense involved. I'm apparently wrong, but don't understand why :(

Comment: you must available your app backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same-origin policy is based on the domains needing to match exactly. `local.abc.com` doesn’t exactly match `someApi.abc.com`. So `http://local.abc.com` and `http://someApi.abc.com` are two completely different origins. So if you have frontend JavaScript code which is running at the origin `http://local.abc.com` and it makes a request to `http://someApi.abc.com`, then that’s a cross-origin request and so CORS gets involved; specifically, browsers will not allow your frontend JavaScript code to access the response from such a request if the `http://someApi.abc.com` site doesn’t send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header in its responses.

Comment: I see. I didn't realize the `someApi` needed to match as well. It will have to be cross-origin then, and it's on the API to return a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response. Do I need to do anything with headers on my end to make sure this will work?

Comment: As far as the CORS protocol goes, you don’t have to do anything with headers on the client side from your frontend code. The only case where special CORS headers are sent from the client side is the Access-Control-Request-Headers & Access-Control-Request-Method request headers—but those are sent by browsers automatically, & only for the CORS preflight OPTIONS requests that browsers do on their own. The Origin request header is also part of the CORS protocol, & is always sent for cross-origin requests from frontend JS—but again that’s a request header browsers automatically add on their own